# Convert a working node.js lesscss workflow to rhino?

Tags: javascript, less, rhino

In a large project for a client we have been using node.js for the less-css konversion, inclusive clean-css, css-link, autoprefixer.js etc. We are very depending on this workflow.

Now the client asked if we could do the same thing using Rhino, Rhino is a javascript engine implimented i java.

I've been researching this for some hours now and even if I am able to compile a less file in a decent way using Rhino I can't find anything about the other plugins we are using, for example autoprefixer.js.

The problem here is that we so far don't have any knowledge at all about rhino but that it feels rather old and haven't been that updated lately. Compared to both node.js and the lessc.

Is there anyone out there in the same situation that we're in? I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [rhinodo](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/rhinodo). it lets you run nodejs module on rhino.

it might not support all modules you need, but you can always contribute to the repo on the ones it doesn't.